# can't print 2d array - file input

Tags: c

maybe this is a very easy question but I'm confused

If my code is named example.c and takes as an input a txt file, lets say `txt.txt` . I run the command `./example txt.txt` in a terminal (linux).
According to what the user gives me through the file, I create a 2D array.
If the context of the fie is:

```
+X..XX....-
.X..X..X-..
.X.........
...XX......
XXX.+X.....
..X.....XXX
...XXX..X-.
.-.....X...
```

I count the lines (in this example 1) and the elements before the new line, to find the rows of my array.

Can you please tell me what I do wrong in the printing of the file into a 2d array?

I can't print the array properly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int lines=0, rows=0, j, k;
    char ch, array[1000][1000];
    FILE *fin;

    if(argc!=2){
        exit(2);
    }

    fin=fopen(argv[1],"r");

    if(fin==NULL) {
        exit(2);
    }
    while(!feof(fin)){
        ch=fgetc(fin);
        if(ch=='\n') lines++;
    }

    fclose(fin);
    fin=fopen(argv[1],"r");

    while(!feof(fin)){
        ch=fgetc(fin);
        if(ch=='+' ||ch=='-'|| ch=='.'||ch=='X') rows++;
        if(ch=='\n') break;
    }

    printf("%d %d\n", lines, rows);
    fclose(fin);
    fin=fopen(argv[1],"r");

    while(!feof(fin)) {
        for(j=0; j<lines; j++){
            for(k=0; k<rows; k++){
                scanf(fin, "%c", &array[j][k]);
            }
        }

        //printf("%d %d", lines, rows);
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<lines; i++){
            for(j=0; j<rows; j++){
                printf("%c", array[i][j]);
                //printf("%d %d\n", i, j);

            }
        }
        fclose(fin);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your program reads the first line only. Also, can you provide a sample input and expected output? What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: I am just testing if it scanfs properly the input.

Comment: See also [why `while(feof(file))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: @Pablo what would u suggest?

Comment: Use `int ch;   ... while ((ch = fgetc(fin)) != EOF) { ... }`

Comment: I don't know about others, but I do not want to spend my time examining a program, trying to determine control flow, etc.  Therefore, for ease of readability and understanding: 1) separate code blocks ( `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` ) via a single blank line.  2) consistently indent the code.  Indent after EVERY opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  3) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value.  If NULL, then call `perror()` to output your text and the reason the system thinks the function failed to `stderr`

Comment: when the incorrect count of command line parameters is recognized, the code should output a `USAGE` message to `stderr`,, similar to `fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s [type of parm1] [...] \n", argv[0] );` then call `exit()`

Comment: regarding: `char ch, array[1000][1000];` 1) for readability should be two lines: the declaration of `array[][]` places a 1000000 byte array on the stack.  This is not a good idea.  Suggest using something similar to `char *array = malloc( 1000*1000 );  if (!array) { perror( "malloc failed" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }

Comment: regarding: `while(!feof(fin)){
    ch=fgetc(fin);`  suggest using `fgets()`  similar to: `while( (ch = fgetc( fin )) != EOF );`     Note: these lines: `fclose(fin);
    fin=fopen(argv[1],"r");`  would be better written as: `rewind( fin );`

Comment: regarding: ` fclose(fin);
        return 0;`  they should be just before the final `}`, not just before the last two: `}}`

Comment: the last `while()` loop can be reduced to:  `char line[1000]; while( fgets( line, sizeof( line ), fin ) ) { printf( "%s", line ); } fclose( fin ); return 0;`

Comment: I have to agree with @user3629249. it 's a real smack in the face that you don't use proper indentation. Especially when you ask for help from thousands of strangers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several problem in your code

1. See [why `while(foef(file))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong). If you are going to read
   the file character by characters, it's best to do it this way:

   ```
   int c;
   while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
   {
       // do somthing with c
   }
   ```
2. Reading the values like this `fscanf(fin, "%c", &array[j][k]);` it's ok, but
   it has one problem: you are forgetting to take the newline into account. You are
   only reading `row` number of characters, but the whole line (assuming there are
   no empty spaces and tabs) has `row+1` characters, the newline didn't go away, so
   when you are finishing reading the last value of a row, the next `scanf` will
   **not** read the next value, it will read a newline. You can fix it by doing
   this:

   ```
   for(j=0; j<lines; j++){
       for(k=0; k<rows; k++){
           fscanf(fin, "%c", &array[j][k]);

       getchar(); // consume the newline
   }
   ```

In general you should read the values line by line using `fgets` and then you
can use `sscanf` to parse the line.

So, to determine the number of lines:

```
int lines = 0;
int c, last = '\n';
while((c = fgetc(fin)) != EOF)
{
    last = c;
    if(c == '\n')
        lines++;
}

// in case the last line does not end with \n
// some file editors don't end the last line with \n
if(last != '\n')
    lines++;
```

To get the number of rows:

```
int rows = 0; 
while((c = fgetc(fin)) != EOF)
{
    // based on your example, the file does not
    // contains other characters than +,-,.,X and newlines
    if(ch == '\n')
        break;
    else
        rows++;
}
```

and now to read the values:

```
// assuming that the file has the correct format and that
// all lines have the same length
char line[rows+2];  // +2 because of the newline and the 0 terminating byte

for(int i = 0; i < lines && i < 1000; ++i)
{
    fgets(line, sizeof line, fin);
    char *tmp = line;
    for(int j = 0; j < rows && j < 1000; ++j)
        sscanf(tmp++, "%c", &array[i][j]);
}
```

Note that this code that the file has the proper format and that all lines have
the same length. In order to make the reading more robust (that means that it
can react to format errors) you'll need to check the return value of `fgets` and
`sscanf`. I've omitted that for sake of simplicity, but you should add these
checks.

And you don't need to open and close `fin` every time, you can use `rewind(fin)`
to set the file at the beginning.

Comment: @Pablo do u believe that a use of a getline function is much more suitable than all that? Is there any simpler way that will eliminate all these possible mistakes?

Comment: @doomandgloom if you're working with a POSIX systems and `getline` is available to you, then yes, you can use that. You would reduce a lot of the code and have less places where things can go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the first line to get the number of `rows`.

```
// Read first line char by char
char ch = fgetc(fin);
while (ch != '\n' && !feof(fin)) {
    rows++;
    ch = fgetc(fin);
}
```

Read remaining lines to get number of lines

```
// Read remaining lines
while (!feof(fin)) {
    if (ch == '\n')
        lines++;
    ch = fgetc(fin);
}
```

Initialize `array` based on number of `lines` and `rows` and read through the file once again. Put non-newline characters to the appropriate location of the `array` by incrementing `j` after each character and `i` after each line.

```
// Initialize array, read again
rewind(fin);
char array[lines][rows];
printf("%d %d\n", lines, rows);

int i = 0; // Current line
int j = 0; // Current row
ch = fgetc(fin);
while (!feof(fin)) {
    if (ch != '\n') {
        array[i][j] = ch;
        j++;
    }
    else if (ch == '\n') {
        i++;
        j = 0;
    }
    ch = fgetc(fin);
}
```

Your read part terminates once it reaches end of file.

To print the array, it is a simple double-loop:

```
// Read array
for (i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
    printf("[");
    for (j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
    printf(" %c ", array[i][j]);
    }
    printf("]\n");
}
```

Comment: I want my program just to read only the first line. this will tell me the number of rows. anything that follows will create the same numbers of rows.

Comment: Initialize counter `rows`. Just check each char of the file, increment `rows` for each char excluding `\n` and stop once you reach `\n`.

Comment: i got segmentation fault

Comment: Although `int ch; while ((ch = fgetc(fin)) != EOF)` is usually the preferred approach, `while (ch != '\n' && !feof(fin)) {` would be OK if it was `while (ch != '\n' && !feof(fin) && !ferror(fin)) {`